# Dynamically change property getters and setters in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, runtime, bind

I'd like to bind my declared properties to controls and views that are created at runtime, much the same way as what happens when using nib / xib files.

The structure of the project is as follows:

- ***plist file:** for setting up a view configuration (buttons, labels, textviews, etc...)*
- ***SOViewController:** a class that should be inherited by any class that wants to make use of the layout manager*.
- ***SOView:** a very basic view that contains a dictionary of generated controls defined in the plist file*
- ***SOLayoutManager:** a singleton responsible for creating the view on behalf of a SOViewController subclass.*

Whenever a custom viewController inherits from `SOViewController`, a plist file with view configuration gets loaded from the bundle. A `SOView` gets created and all controls are added to the view by the `SOLayoutManager` (and are also accessible through a dictionary that's part of the view). The custom view controller should bind the properties with the controls generated from the plist file (the controls that are part of the `SOView` instance).

My question is as follows: how do I bind the getter and setter methods of the properties contained in my custom view controller with the controls generated in the `SOView` subclass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way xib's do it... call `setValue:forKey:`

If you have something like this

```
@interface MyViewController : SOViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *myButton;

// ...

@end
```

when the `SOLayoutManager` creates the view components it would see if it has an `outlet` and connect it up

```
MyViewController *viewController = // ...

// Create and configure the button
[viewController setValue:configuredButton forKey:@"myButton"];
```

You would need to add the name of the outlet to the plist so it knows what to set it on

Comment: Yay, so easy - and here I was thinking I had to do some C coding with the objc/runtime API :)